# How to unset default tab in Spry Tabbed Panel in dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, spry

I have a Spry Tabbed Panel in Dreamweaver and the first tab is open when the page is loading. I don't want to have any tab opened when the page is loaded.
How can i do this?

Thanks!

That's my html:

```
  <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
  <li class="TabbedPanelsTab play" tabindex="0"><h4>Play! Framework</h4></li>
  <li class="TabbedPanelsTab ruby" tabindex="1"><h4>Ruby on Rails</h4></li>
  <li class="TabbedPanelsTab api" tabindex="2"><h4>Restful Api</h4></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the clumsiest workaround available but at least it's easy to do. Locate your `SpryTabbedPanels.js` file and see what the first function looks like. If you have somewhere a line `this.defaultTab = 0;` comment it and see what happens. It should make the panels invisible.

You might also want to get rid of javaScript error so find a line that contains `panels[tpIndex].style.display = "block";` and replace it with:

```
if(panels[tpIndex]){
  panels[tpIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```

Actually you need to do also the second correction if you have more than one panel groups on the page. Otherwise only the first panel group is hidden.

This should work. At least it works for me for Spry made with DW CS3. But it looks ugly IMHO. No transitions/animations. But at least no panels are visible when the page is loaded for the first time. The tabs, of course, are visible.

Comment: Thank you! It works!    
I just needed to erase defaultTab too in the code below:
    
`<script type="text/javascript">    
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1", { defaultTab: 0 });    
</script>`

Comment: @Sandra Glad to know this helped even if it seems we have different versions of Spry in use (mine is v1.4 from 2006, ouch...). Check also your error log if you get any errors. In this old Spry version `display` `block` is given to the selected tab but it can't be given because after the page load no tab is selected (since the default tab is omitted).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul > li').removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: Thanks but where i should put this code? Actually i don't understand javascript. I've changed the CSS of the Tabbed Panel but i don't changed anything in the javascript.

Comment: Your answer is a jQuery answer - Sandra is asking for a JavaScript answer.

Answer (score 0):

SpryCollapsiblePanel.js

Top section:

```
this.contentIsOpen = false;
```

(replace true by false)

Dreamweaver CS6